# Triangulation algorithm for mobile geolocation detection

Tags: triangulation

Please help with algorithm for getting **radius** (L) and **center** decimal coordinates (X) of blue circle.
[Drawing here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2691093/geolocation.png)

Following points are given:

c1 = 56.963022,24.640274 r1 = 6km
c2 = 56.878324,24.490585 r2 = 5km
c3 = 56.870819,24.746017 r3 = 8km

Answer should be in following format:
X = XX.XXXXXX;
L = X.XX km

PS. I need this for creating software for my Master's work and I am a web programmer, not mathematician, so please try not to use very scientific language :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For small distances like this, you can consider the earth to be flat.  We will use $R$ for the radius of the earth, $\lambda$ for latitude and $\phi$ for longitude.  If you pick one of the points to be the origin, the distance in $y$ (north/south) is $R (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)\frac \pi{180}$ and the distance in $x$ (east/west) is $R \cos \lambda (\phi_2-\phi_1)\frac \pi{180}$, where the $\frac \pi{180}$ factor comes because your angles are degrees.  Then you can use the formlae in [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) to find the points where the circles intersect.  The center of your blue circle is the [centroid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCentroid.html) of the triangle.