# Finding a geolocation that is approximately $d$ distance from a given geolocation

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, spherical-coordinates, geodesy

I have a geolocation represented using latitude and longitude: $({\phi_1,\lambda_1})$ and a given distance in meters $d$.

I want to find an equation for all the geolocations $({\phi_2,\lambda_2})$ that are **approximately** $d$ meters from the first location.

I won't be dealing with locations more than a few kilometers away from each other, and margin of error can be quite wide, so a rough approximation should be good enough.

I tried to adapt questions such as [How to find a point on a line at a given distance from a given point on the same line (given the equation of the line)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042178/how-to-find-a-point-on-a-line-at-a-given-distance-from-a-given-point-on-the-same) and [Triangulation algorithm for mobile geolocation detection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219586/triangulation-algorithm-for-mobile-geolocation-detection) , but I find it too hard to adapt to geolocation units.

I also tried to reverse the approximation equation from this [reference](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), but could not simplify it enough:

$x=(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)\cos(\frac{\phi_1+\phi_2}{2})$

$y=\phi_2-\phi_1$

$d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}R$

With $R$ being earth radius in meters `6371e3`

Edit:

If anyone interested, javascript code based on the answer:

```
const toRadians = (value) => value * Math.PI / 180;

const toDegrees = (value) => value * 180 / Math.PI;

const R = 6371e3;

const getRandomLocation = ({latitude, longitude, distance}) => {
    const degree = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
    const noise = toRadians(degree);
    const phi = toRadians(latitude);
    const lambda = toRadians(longitude);

    const randLatitude = toDegrees(phi + (distance / R) * Math.cos(noise));
    const randLongitude = toDegrees(lambda + (distance / R) * (Math.sin(noise) / Math.cos(phi)));
    console.info(`(${latitude},${longitude}) (${distance}m, ${degree}°)-> (${randLatitude},${randLongitude})`);
    return {latitude: randLatitude, longitude: randLongitude};
};
```

Comment: You may like to look at the graph script I posted in a comment on Intelligenti pauca's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cartesian equation can be found from your last formulas. I'd only substitute $\cos(\phi_1+\phi_2)/2$ with $\cos\phi_1$:
$$
(\phi_2-\phi_1)^2+(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^2\cos^2\phi_1={d^2\over R^2}.
$$
If you want an explicit formula you can solve for either angle, e.g.:
$$
\phi_2=\phi_1\pm\sqrt{{d^2\over R^2}-(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^2\cos^2\phi_1}.
$$
Alternatively, you can introduce a rotation angle $\theta$ and write a parametric equation:
$$
\phi_2=\phi_1+{d\over R}\cos\theta;
\quad
\lambda_2=\lambda_1+{d\over R}{\sin\theta\over\cos\phi_1}.
$$
EDIT.

The above formulas work if the angles are expressed in radians: please make the appropriate conversions if the angles are given in degrees.

Comment: Since the OP is (presumably) measuring latitude & longitude in degrees, it may be a good idea to make that explicit in the parametric equations. So rather than writing $\frac{d}{R}$, we have $\frac{d×360°}{2\pi R}$. With $d$ in km, that simplifies to (approximately) $\frac{d}{111.1949}$

Comment: @PM2Ring You are right, thanks: the above formulas work if the angles are expressed in radians. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Here's a Sage / Python script which plots the error of your circle equation, for a circle centred on 0° longitude, any latitude (as long as it's not too close to a pole), with radius in metres. My code uses the [haversine formula for the great circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). As you can see, the error is very small for smallish radii. For larger circles, we'd need to use the ellipsoid distance.

Comment: [Graph script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1ks9OxCAQxu99ikkvCxXXtv7JakLiRY--gNEGW3aLFqjA6us70HatBzm0MPPx8WOYvbMatAjjYMOg3rZBtR_SgdKjdQEezOHROkwH6bKsqx1wGBVcQLUrM92M0jWdPGCwwnF7vS13qJJ7aJVrySACAyc6Bl626R96epcBjtBDwQH90srJcHQGUA9ncQMU0FpPUL1sxYhXJkYm_158kTB7zbtTHslq-lrPEJ3yIVKULHpX-LVm3hSja4SYX6893ikekuLnSU4RLmJN82KZV3GepNbgDA3oGsuQGqMi0vlPF4inFCGTKrtXBusq2pBwtUANGvKrMpWt0Zzk-FdHD0TTnEFVliVdbo1F4ZMM_U5PMcFPNUtpTM6gC1ySxAODxPKcnmTFfCocg-L_l4z3_m2B84llco_NRKI9A4KXubxB7K3v7Tc5ONUNykjPcy3ercvZfHjsu2a_9Bp_frJGsj_9R45GBb7RG_pCfwCkXctI&lang=sage)